# Switch login form to register form with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I searched around but i didn't find anything close to what I want. I have a login form and a register form on the same page, one after another. I am not so good with jquery, I'm still learning. I want to have the login on the first time and then if the client doesn't have and account, click on register and the login form will fade out and the register form will fade in, on the same place on page.

Please someone give me a help with the jquery code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="remember">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login__submit">
<p class="login__signup">Don't have an account? &nbsp;<a>Sign up</a></p>
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php  echo escape(Input::get('username')); //this is for sticky form ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_again">Password again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Anyway, you should not be looking for the exact thing that you want. You should be learning the basics of javascript and jquery so that you can use those basic skills to build anything you'd like to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904965/html-jquery-toggle-between-two-forms

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code that I have used in my project to show and hide login and register form on click of login and register button

I have created a simple jquery code, that disables and enables the relevent form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$("#login_btn").click(function() {
    console.log('login btn clicked');
    $("#registerForm").hide();
    $("#loginForm").show();


});

$("#register_btn").click(function() {
    console.log('regsiter btn clicked');
    $("#loginForm").hide();
    $("#registerForm").show();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
<div id="signin_div">

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="remember">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login__submit">
<p class="login__signup">Don't have an account? &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showSignUp">Sign up</a></p>
</form>

</div>

<div id="signup_div">

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php  echo escape(Input::get('username')); //this is for sticky form ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_again">Password again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showSignUp").click(function(){
        $("#signin_div").hide();
        $("#signup_div").show();

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Ahamed I don't want the register form to show up at the first time. Register form should be hided and only login form to be viewed. And when you click sigh up login form will be hided and the register form will show up.

Comment: Add this to above code :: <style>
#signup_div {
    display: none;
}
</style>

Comment: My friend if javascript is disabled this code will not run `<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showSignUp">Sign up</a> `

Comment: Yes. If javascript is disabled it wont work. You cannot implement without javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#log_in").click(function(){
        $(".login_form").css('display', 'none');
        $(".display_none").css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

```css
.display_none
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login_form">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login__submit">
        <p class="login__signup">Don't have an account? &nbsp;<a href="#" id="log_in">Sign up</a></p>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class ="display_none">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="password_again">Password again</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="name" name="name" id="name" >
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="token" >
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the result that I was looking for:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".register").hide();
    $("#showSignUp").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".login").fadeToggle("slow");
        $(".register").toggle(1000);

    });
});

</script>
```

without any js inserted in the html code, or modify the css page.